# Add own IronPython DLL to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, python, dll

I have created a dll using IronPython.

How can I use the dll in Visual Studio C# ? I have tried to add the dll using **AddReference** but I couldn't see its contents.

Comment: You have to add a reference of your `.dll` and in your C# project you have to include its namespace with all the other defaults `using` assignments,

Comment: Your `dll` is an assembly. You need a dissassembler to view the code again. Because at this state of time its just IL code.